# cordova Facebook connect plugin fail on login ! Facebook error: failed to receive access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I am getting problem while logging through facebook

```
"cordova Facebook connect plugin fail on login ! Facebook error: failed to receive access token"
```

On emulator its working fine. But on mobile device its getting trouble. Is there any problem in facebook settngs. Sandbox mode is also disabled

```
"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" its "yes"
```

please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify following lines in your www directory:

***index.html***:

```
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"> </script>
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

**config.xml**:

```
<gap:plugin name="FacebookConnect">
  <param name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
  <param name="APP_NAME" value="BenTen"/>
</gap:plugin> 
<access origin="*" subdomains="true">
```

Comment: I dont have config.xml file in project res/xml directory. I dont have config.xml file in project only. And when i created that file under res/xml it showing the erroe at line "<access origin="*" sub-domains="true">"   Error is "Multiple markers at this line
- The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
- error: Error parsing XML: no element found" i have two files in xml folder 1) cardova.xml 2) plugins.xml

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought your using phonegap build.

Comment: I am using cordova phonegap.